# What does this "their" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, plural-forms, pronouns, gender

> "But who'd be that desperate?" he wondered aloud. "If you're going to
>   be cursed forever, death's better, isn't it?" 
>       "It is," Firenze agreed, "unless all you need is to stay alive long enough to drink something else –– something that will bring you
>   back to full strength and power –– something that will mean you can
>   never die. Mr. Potter, do you know what is hidden in the school at
>   this very moment?" 
>       "The Sorcerer's Stone! Of course –– the Elixir of Life! But I don't understand who ––" 
>       "Can you think of nobody who has waited many years to return to power, who has clung to life, awaiting **their** chance?" (Harry
>   Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

I guess ‘their’ does not have a plural meaning here but it is a substitute for his or her. Is this right?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

This usage of `their` as a singular possessive pronoun to replace `his or her` was uncommon enough to sound jarring and incorrect to me several years ago, but has become very common more recently.

Similarly, `they` and `them` are now used as a singular pronoun where `he or she` and `him or her` would previously have been used. Even longer ago, the male form alone was used!

This change in common usage is partly because of objections to a former use of `he` to mean `he or she`, but to be fair, the use of these plurals as singulars has a very long history indeed, despite none of that history coinciding with my childhood in the UK!